# OnCheckedChanged not working in Asp.Net and VB (codebehind)

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a problem with the trigger of the OnCheckedChanged. When I click the checkbox (switch toggle), the OnCheckedChanged is not firing. I already tried many solutions like trigger it in JS part but no luck.

Below is the checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="secondary" data-on="Ja" data-off="Nee" data-size="xs" runat="server" 
                        oncheckedchanged="showProductFoto_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                        style="margin-top: -5px;"  runat="server" id="showProductFoto" onchange="IncludeWithoutPhotos(this)" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Comment: OnCheckedChanged is for webforms `<asp:CheckBox` controls rather than `<input type="checkbox"` html elements.

Comment: any particular reason why you don't just drag + drop in a asp.net checkbox as opposed to using a html one?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I used the HTLM one because the CSS and toggle of the checkbox is not working in <asp:CheckBox.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I used the HTLM one because the CSS and toggle of the checkbox is not working in <asp:CheckBox.

Comment: Then my advice is to do this in javascript. CheckChanged is generally a poor fit for webforms server events anyway, since any server event requires rebuilding the page from scratch and sending a whole new html document back to the browser.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn If by change, do you have any sample code? Below is what I am trying...  

$('#showProductFoto').trigger('change');

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I saw that in result when researching but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then get the css working for the check box, and then you back to using the standard asp.net controls - and they are a pure joy to use, and easy to use.

So, say I have this check box:

```
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" 
            runat="server" Text="Confirm to send email"
            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" >
```

We get this ugly thing:

[image]

so, I can see your motivation to want to dump that ugly above.

but, a check box gets renderd as a html input (type = checkbox), and also puts in a label for you.

So, you can style it anyway you want.

Say, like this:

```
     <style>
        .bigcheck input {width:28px;height:28px;cursor:pointer;
                         box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey}
        .bigcheck label {position:absolute;margin-left:15px;margin-top:10px}
    </style>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" CssClass="bigcheck"
            runat="server" Text="Confirm to send email"
            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

And now we get this:

[image]

so, you still have quite much unlimited css you can apply against that check box.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. How about the "data-togggle..etc" part? I'm using Boostrap-toggle by the way.